# Change text color from InputMethodService

Tags: android

I'm modifying gingerbread keyboard. I want to change the color of the text that i'm entering.
Its possible when I'm entering the text using `InputConnection.setComposingText(CharSequence, cursorPosition)` since the argument of the method `setComposingText` allows a `Spannable` type. But when I press the space button, that is, when the text is committed, the color goes back to default.

`InputConnection`'s `commitText` method takes the same arguments as the `setComposingText`. But the color is not changed. How can I overcome the problem?

will appreciate any help

Comment: android:textColor="@color/red"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### public abstract boolean [commitText](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/inputmethod/InputConnection.html#commitText%28java.lang.CharSequence,%20int%29) (CharSequence text, int newCursorPosition)

> ```
> Commit text to the text box and set the new cursor position. Any composing text set previously will be removed automatically.
> ```

commitText function sends only the raw text to a TextBox removing any special composing styling or other state that was around it. Because it is up to the application what it should do with the text and not the responsibility of an **Input Method**. What style a text can support depends totally on the respective app.

Comment: I read that.. I badly need a workaround though maybe by exteding InputConnectionBase class?. It should be possible, what if I want to set a custom font.

Comment: Let me clarify a bit more. You can only use custom font or anything else within your view (say a custom view attached with your input method). Say, a specific app shows whatever text you enter in **Blue** color, if you send text to this app in another color it makes the raw text to its default color blue. Another example: Say you use Spannable String and replace **:)** with a corresponding smiley image but this doesn't mean that a specific app will be able to use the image instead of :). I'm saying again **it depends on the app**. Input method works system wide for all the apps (sms,contact..)

Comment: You can only send **raw text** from input method.